# Integrating an Exponent in the Denominator

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

What are the rules to how this is done? Is it add 1 to the numerator of the exponent, then flip that exponent and put it out front, and still keep the exponent? I'm lost.

Comment: $a^{-b}=\frac1{a^b}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{1}{U^{1/3}}$ is the same as $U^{-1/3}$. Do you know the rule for integrating regular exponents?